# Python commpy library error: no module named 'filters'

Tags: python, scikits

I have recently installed a library using this code:

```
pip install scikit-commpy
```

Moreover, I downloaded the tar.gz file from this site: https://pypi.org/project/scikit-commpy/#files and launch the setup.py file, but when I do this on python to check the installation:

```
import commpy
```

It gives me the following error:

```
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\commpy\__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from filters import *

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'filters'
```

Comment: What version of python are you running? Are you using an environment like Anaconda? And BTW since you installed using 'pip install scikit-commpy' you don't have to also download it.

Comment: I'm able to replicate this in `python3.6` anaconda

Comment: I'm using python 2 so I used '!pip2 install scikit-commpy' in jupyter and was able to import commpy.

Comment: It didn't work for me in python3 though. Perhaps the module doesn't support python3.

Comment: if it wasn't supported in `python3` I wouldn't imagine it would be `pip`-installable

Comment: I´m using python 3.6 in Anaconda

Comment: @techcyclist you're right, the library has python2 syntax for `print`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it looks like the `__init__.py` file in that directory has broken imports somehow. I was able to fix it in `vim` by changing the import to:

#### **init**.py

```py
from .filters import *
from .modulation import *
from .impairments import *
from .sequences import *
```

I'm not sure how that will impact other functionalities in the module, but that does allow me to run

```py
import commpy
```

with no errors.

### NOTE

It appears this behavior is further down in the module as well, so if you were to attempt

```py
from commpy import channelcoding
```

it will `raise` similar exceptions. So you will have to do more surgery on the module in `./commpy/channelcoding/__init__.py`:

```py
from .convcode import Trellis, conv_encode, viterbi_decode
from .interleavers import *
from .turbo import turbo_encode, map_decode, turbo_decode
from .ldpc import ldpc_decode
from .gfields import *
from .algcode import *
```

#### Upon further inspection, the syntax of this library is python2

Comment: @Josemi I made an edit to encompass the whole module

Comment: But if I do that, it appears:
`File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\commpy\channelcoding\__init__.py", line 66, in <module>
    from .ldpc import ldpc_decode

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\commpy\channelcoding\ldpc.py", line 53
    print "Perfect Decoding, # Iterations: " + str(i+1)
                                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: @Josemi wow that's bizarre looking. What command kicked that off?

Comment: @Josemi that's python2 syntax

Comment: That's true, I didn't realise. I'm changing the syntax to python 3, but for the following sentence: `raise ValueError, "The arguments should have the same number of elements"`, what would be its equivalent in python 3?

Comment: `raise ValueError("The arguments...")`

Comment: Ok, thank you a lot. It also gave me the error in file `/algcode.py`: no module named 'gflieds', but I did `from .gfield import GF, polymultiply, poly_to_string`, and that was the last error